# Computer starts up two seconds after shutdown

Tags: shutdown, computer-building

My Gigabyte GA EP41T UD3L  restarts after shutdown, even when no HDD is connected.
I tried to change the

- CPU
- RAM
- RAM slot
- graphics card
- with HDD
- without HDD
- with DVD-ROM
- power button
- restart button
- new OS (old Windows XP instead of Windows 7)
- and I even updated the BIOS to the latest (F7)

and it's still not shutting down. If a hardware change is required I can do it.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it directly? and what method are you using to shutdown?

Comment: Try changing the power supply

Comment: This could also be a setting in your network adapter driver. Look for "Wake on LAN" or "Wake on Magix packet". Also check the "Power managment" of that driver for something that your card can wake your computer up.

Answer (score 2):

When you see something like this it's usually a setting buried in your BIOS configuration. Look somewhere in your BIOS power settings for an 'Auto Power On' or 'Reinstate AC'.

Also check to see if you're plugged into a UPS system / Power strip that is causing this. There are many uninterruptable power supplies (not your PSU in your PC) that are set to power your device back on after seeing it shut off.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turned out to be an electrical issue between the motherboard screws and the case of the computer tower touching. I had to use some sort of grounding red circles made of paper between the screws and case of computer and it never happened again.